# How to get multiple SLD files of the same shapefile?

Tags: arcmap, sld

I need to get multiple SLD files for the same shapefile. Geometry is polygons, and they need to be colored by one attribute column.  What is the best solution? I'm working with ArcMap2SLD or ArcMap to SLD Converter.

Comment: can you expand on what the differences between your styles will be?

Comment: Ten objects which have value 1 in attribute column "Species1" would have light green color, eight objects which have value 1 in attribute column "Species2" will have dark green color etc. For every attribute column I need one SLD file (for example "Species1" - one SLD file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to create the first SLD file using which ever tool you like. The copy it and edit it using a text editor to change the filter to point to the next column and change the colour as required.

Though from you description you should be able to have one SLD file with all the criteria in it, unless an object can have a 1 in multiple columns.